# Get more accuracy DeepLab then the pretrainned model

Tags: tensorflow, deeplab

I have a question in deeplab v3 accuracy right now the best accuracy(mIOU) achieved by the model xception65_coco_voc_trainval 87.80. I was wondering that can we further increase it if i train the model for less number of class lets say for person only using the same dataset or it will not make any difference.
The problem is along the edges model has problem identifying it correctly. The orignal image had all green background and after applying the mask some greenish remains. So 2 questions in short
1. If i train for single class then will accuracy improve ?
2.  If not then is there any other method i can apply to achive better results
Note:
Background doesn't have to be green in all cases.
i saw the remove.bg website and they have done good job, does any one knows what approach have they taken to achieve good results
Thanks

[image]